# How to unzip folder in IOS iPhone application

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to unzip folder with in my iPhone application. Can any one help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to use **[SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive)** in order to working with zip files.

Below line would unzip your zip file.

```
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:path toDestination:destination];
```

Comment: This is great for ZIP64 compatibility but it is SLOW on zip files with many small files in them.

Answer (score 5):

Download zipArchieve.zip file which used to unzip files in iPhone.

It contains following things...

[zipArchieve.zip   click here to download](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list)

1.minizip folder 
    2.ZipArchive.h    
  3.ZipArchive.mm

Then just drag & drop `ZipArchive` folder in to xCode "Classes".

Then add framework `libz.1.2.3.dylib`.

That's it. My code get compile without any issue.

Comment: In Xcode 4.6 i was unable to find libz.1.2.3.dylib.But adding libz.1.1.3.dylib worked for me

Comment: This is incompatible with Zip64 (+4GB or +65535 files) zip files.  Best to use ssArchive as stated above.  Minizip 1.0.x is not zip64 aware--nor does zipArchive handle it.

Answer (score 1):

USE [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list)

Comment: can I use zipArchieve for ios 6