# Save multiple files as one package with custom file type

Tags: ios, import, export, file-extension

I need to save multiple files as one custom file, which then can be exported and imported into the iOS app. The files that go into this package are PDFs and TXTs.

A .pages file on the Mac is pretty much exactly what I want, it is a package which contains the original files, but acts as a custom (Pages) file.

I looked into NSFileWrapper, NSKeyedArchiver and NSFileManager, but I can't find the right way to solve this problem. How can I export multiple files into one package on iOS, that I can save with my own file extension and where I can easily get the original files out when importing?

Comment: Can you not just zip with a custom extension?

Comment: I thought about that, but then I need a framework for that I guess. I thought there might be a simple way to create such a package file of a directory.

Comment: Indeed, but it's trivial with SSZipArchive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786835/how-to-unzip-folder-in-ios-iphone-application