# iOS :: How to decompress .gz file using GZIP Utility?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I have kept my sqlite database in the S3 server in the .gz format. 
When my iOS App starts, I want to download the database in .gz file and decompress it in the documents directory.

Download part is working fine but decompression is not working.

I tried ZipArchive, but it doesn't decompress .gz file. It is able to unzip ZIP files. Below is the code, I tried.

```
 ZipArchive *za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

if ([za UnzipOpenFile:filePath]) {
    BOOL ret = [za UnzipFileTo:destPath overWrite:YES];
    [za UnzipCloseFile];
    [za release];

    if (ret == YES) {
        [self stopSpinner];

                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[appDelegate encTitle] message:@"Update successful.\nPlease restart the application for changes to take effect." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
            } else {
                //Didn't work
            }
        }
```

I found GZIP for decompression in iOS, but don't have any idea to use this. If anyone has idea, please share with me.
Link for GZIP :: https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP

If anyone knows any other library for .gz decompression.....they are also welcome.

Comment: Read this answer from Brad Larson: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230984/compression-api-on-the-iphone/234099#234099

Comment: This is an alternative easiest solution .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786835/how-to-unzip-folder-in-ios-iphone-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What specifically are you having difficulty with using the GZIP library?

All you need to do is call `gunzippedData` on an `NSData` instance and it will return a new `NSData` object with the unzipped data.

**Update**

The GZIP library does not work with files, however it works directly with instances of `NSData`. This means you will have to [construct an `NSData` object from your compressed .gz file](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfFile:options:error:) manually, uncompress it, and [write the uncompressed data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:atomically:) to the documents directory...

```
// assuming filePath is a valid local path to the .gz file
NSError *error = nil;

// Create an NSData instance from the file
NSData *compressedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:0 error:&error];
if (!compressedData) {
    NSLog(@"Reading file failed: %@", error);
}
else {
    // Attempt to uncompress it
    NSData *uncompressedData = [compressedData gunzippedData];
    if (!uncompressedData) {
        NSLog(@"Decompression failed");
    }
    else {
        // Write the uncompressed data to disk
        // You will need to set pathToSQLiteFile to the desired location of the SQLite database
        [uncompressedData writeToFile:pathToSQLiteFile atomically:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am very new to iOS, So don't have much idea about iOS code.....I am not able to find where and how to set the zipped file name and the destination path.

Comment: I've added some example code that you should be able to use.

Comment: i am getting "class method +gunzippedData not found" error....eventhough i have imported GZIP.h file

Comment: Oops, my apologies, I had incorrectly called [NSData gunzippedData], it should have been [compressedData gunzippedData]. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Steve....Thank you so much...you saved my lot of time...Now decompression works fine...

Comment: Hey Steve...can you please help me in my next question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385368/downloading-files-in-serial-order-using-nsurlconnection-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a lightweight **Swift 3+** wrapper library around Apple's own compression library called [DataCompression](https://github.com/mw99/DataCompression). Among others it also supports the **GZIP** format.

Decompressing a **.gz** text file and printing the content would look like this:

```
import DataCompression

let compressedData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/your/file.txt.gz"))

if let uncompressedData = compressedData?.gunzip() {
    print(String(data: uncompressedData, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Can't decode UTF-8")
}
```

You may refer to the [README](https://github.com/mw99/DataCompression/blob/master/README.md) for a complete overview of the interface and other compression formats.